# datetime expected float, got string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pyautogui, timedelta

I'm trying to make a pyautogui script that adds the users input to the current time using the datetime/timedelta module. I want the pyautogui part to use `typewrite` and type out the result to a website (current time + user input) `new_time = now + xtime`.

My code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

xtime = (input("enter a time in numbers: "))

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now + timedelta(hours=xtime)
new_time = now + xtime
pyautogui.typewrite(new_time)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

I get these error messages

> Expected type 'float', got 'str' instead

> Unexpected type(s):(str)Possible type(s):(timedelta)(timedelta)

Please can someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: consider cleaning up your imports; make it one line `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` to avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly self-explanatory. When you construct an object of type `datetime.timedelta`, it's expecting an argument of type `float`. The `input` function returns a string, though.

Try:

```
xtime = float(input("enter a time in numbers: "))
```

Your indentation also appears to be off, which will cause errors in Python.

Comment: How would I fix "Unexpected type(s):(float)Possible type(s):(timedelta)(timedelta)"?

Answer (score 0):

`timedelta()` requires hours to be a number, so I've converted it to an integer. Also I've formatted the time using `.strftime()` to make it more readable.

Try and see if these works:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

xtime = input("enter a time in hours: ")

now = datetime.datetime.now()
new_time = (now + timedelta(hours=int(xtime))).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
print(new_time)
pyautogui.typewrite(new_time)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Output:

```
enter a time in hours:  2
2022-05-16T22:45:49
```